# Is there a standard wireless recovery procedure?

Tags: raspbian, wireless

I am running a Raspberry Pi Zero with Raspbian 25-Nov-2016.
My wireless network goes out every few hours and I have to restart it to recover it.
I need to run it headless. Is there a standard set of steps to try to recover?
I am writing the following script to call from /etc/crontab every 3 hours. Please help improve it.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Writing to syslog
exec 1> >(logger -s -t $(basename "$0")) 2>&1

echo "Checking Connection"

if ! ping -c1 someserver.com
then 
    echo "Connection FAIL. Restarting networking"
    /etc/init.d/networking restart
else
    echo "Connection OK"
    exit 0
fi

sleep 60
if ! ping -c1 someserver.com
then 
    echo "Connection FAIL. Restarting Linux"
    /sbin/shutdown -r +2 
else
    echo "Connection OK"
    exit 0
fi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My case is Pi 3, but I am experiencing the similar problem (sometimes it goes out every few minutes) and researched the solution before.

They said the first things you should do is to make Pi gets enough amperage. A Good power supply is a must.

Next, disable the power-saving mode. To do it, you could modify your wifi setting in `/etc/network/interfaces` like following

```
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
    post-up /sbin/iw dev wlan0 set power_save off
```

Both didn't fix my wifi problem, and I couldn't find a standard way to fix it, so I wrote a similar script like yours.

```
#!/bin/bash
(
    flock -n 199 || exit 1
    IFACE=wlan0
    /sbin/ifconfig $IFACE | grep -q inet
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        DATE=`(date +"%Y/%m/%d %T")`
        echo $DATE : $IFACE is down. trying to reconnect. | sudo tee > /dev/kmsg
        /sbin/ifdown $IFACE >> /dev/null 2>&1
        /bin/sleep 3
        /sbin/ifup $IFACE >> /dev/null 2>&1
    fi
)199>/var/lock/wlan0-reconnect.lock
```

I run the script every minute by corn. It might be excessive but I'm using it as a media server so didn't want to lose the connection.

For the coding, I didn't use `ping -c1` because it always lost IP address itself, so I wanted to speed up the checking process. Also, I use `flock()` to block overlapping command line execution. (Yes, I'm short tempered and run the script whenever I found the internet connection is lost :)